# 3d Voxel coordinates as list in Matlab

Tags: matlab, 3d, vectorization, voxel

I have a cube of 20*20*20 cm^3 and voxels of 1cm^3, how do I get the coordinates of all the 20*20*20=8000 voxel centers as a list of [x,y,z] (size 8000*3)? Preferably in vectorized form! Thanks a lot!

Comment: What do you mean by "coordinates"? Can you give an example in a small case, say 2x2x2?

Comment: For 2*2*2 I need
[
(0.5,0.5,0.5),
(0.5,0.5,1.5),
(0.5,1.5,0.5),
(0.5,1.5,1.5),
(1.5,0.5,0.5),
(1.5,0.5,1.5),
(1.5,1.5,0.5),
(1.5,1.5,1.5)
]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ndgrid`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/ndgrid.html) does the job:

```
N = 20;
[z, y, x] = ndgrid(.5:N); %// note reverse order to get desired order of result
xyz = [x(:) y(:) z(:)]; %// desired result
```